# Why Intrinsic Matrix Init faster in colmun using transpose?

Tags: c++, matrix, intrinsics

I was experimenting with creating my matrix in row and column major in memory ( row major = all 4 axis of transform matrix are contiguous in memory ), and there something that really puzzle me, it's faster in Column ( using Transpose ).

For 10M operation, in release full optimization, in same condition ( so same data cache ), with precompute 10M size vector.

(30/05/2014@14:55:48) Log : [3] ( Mat.Set 4 Axis Row Major ) = 268.785071 ms

(30/05/2014@14:56:20) Log : [3] ( Mat.Set 4 Axis Column Major ) = 209.204404 ms

So the row major creation look like this ( Mat4 is __m128[4] m_axis ), so this will simply copy 4 __m128.

```
void Mat4::Set(const Vec4& axisX,const Vec4& axisY,const Vec4& axisZ,const Vec4& pos)
{
        m_axis[cX].Set(     axisX   );
        m_axis[cY].Set(     axisY   );
        m_axis[cZ].Set(     axisZ   );
        m_axis[EPos].Set(   pos     );
}
```

And for the column major I must transpose the 4 axis, using my own _MM_TRANSPOSE_M4 wich is just storing the result in my m_axis array copied from _MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS

```
void Mat4::SetColumn(const Vec4& axisX,const Vec4& axisY,const Vec4& axisZ,const Vec4& pos)
{
_MY_TRANSPOSE4_PS(  axisX.m_val,    axisY.m_val,    axisZ.m_val,    pos.m_val,
            m_axis[cX],     m_axis[cY],     m_axis[cZ],     m_axis[EPos]    );
}
```

How can the SetColumn could be so faster, I'm guessing the SIMD cpu is doing several opration at the same time, but how can I increase my row major creation code?

Hope you can enlighten me.
Thanks for Reading.

---

Edit : sample code to profile

```
mssFloat*   values = MssNew mssFloat[nb*4];
for (mssSizeT idx = 0; idx < nb*4; idx++)
{
    values[idx] = mssFloat(10.0f * rand() / RAND_MAX);
}
{
    MsS::CProfilingCounter profCounter("Vec.Set 4 Float");
    for (mssSizeT idx = 0; idx < nb; idx++)
        vectors[idx].Set( values[idx*4],values[idx*4+1],values[idx*4+2],values[idx*4+3]);
}
{
    MsS::CProfilingCounter profCounter("Mat.Set 4 Axis ");
    for( mssSizeT l=0;l<loop;l++)
    {
        for (mssSizeT idx = 0; idx < nb; idx++)
            mat4Array2[idx] = MsS::Mat4( vectors[idx],vectors[nb-idx],vectors[idx%10],vectors[idx%10]);
    }
}
```

Same sample for both test, I just change the Mat4 constructor to initialize matrix in row major or col major in memory.

Comment: Because your data apparently is bigger than cache, and you are doing no compute intensive work, the speed difference could be due to DRAM memory access efficiency. If the data to initialize is really big, using a non-temporal store intrinsic might be even faster. The fastest large write is sequential, non-temporal. If you could post a working sample, others could comment more easily.

Comment: Hi,well, I try to make sample that will reflect normal use, which is working on big meshes, which have lot's of vertices. So yeah, data is bigger than cache, that's intended ;) my sample is quite simple, first create 1Mx4 random floats, then init 1M vectors with them, then the profiling, just sequentialy init 1M matrices with vectors.I tried to separate things to just profil the init of matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the additions. Probably due to my lack of C++ know-how, I don't see how to compile this code into an executable for profiling. I wrote my own C code program to see if I understand more (http://notabs.org/temp/sample.c). It creates 10M __m128 elements and initializes them with valid random float values. Then it initializes another using this data. Assign takes 41.3ms, temporal store 22.1 ms, and non-temporal store 19.6 ms. Assign ends up using memcpy. Others read using movaps, then movaps for store (or movntps for the non-temporal case).

Comment: my assign ends up using _mm_set_ps not memcopy, hmm, that's a first difference. And I as you can see I start from a 10M float, not __m128, because that's where my meshes will be stored from and read from file.
Also, I continue my lib now rendering DX11, and DXmatrix are row major, but HLSL matrixes from shader ARE colmu, major ;) which definitively make me decided to use colmun major too ;)

Comment: How is Vec4.Set defined?  What is `_MY_TRANSPOSE4_PS` (I know what _MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS` but not `_MY_TRANSPOSE4_PS`)

Comment: _MY is the same as _MM i just changed so the result is stored directly in my matrix. It's just a different writing, the final code in optimized code should be the same. And Vec is just and __m128.